# Spring Boot Tomcat won't start on specific port

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat

I want to run a Spring Boot application using Maven but when I run

```
mvn clean install spring-boot:run -Dserver.port=8888
```

Spring runs on port 8080. How should I run a Maven Spring Boot application on a specific port?

I use Spring Boot version 2.2.6.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

-Dserver.port is not passed to the JVM running your app.

You have to use

```
mvn clean install spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.arguments="--server.port=8888"
```

Read more about this:
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-command-line-arguments

Comment: In my case Idea was not taking the env var. Just making a `mvn clean` and relauching solves the problem